# Not possible to create index

Tags: python, devpi

I have my local `devpi` working fine. I can create a new user, and login as this new user:

```
# Login as root
» devpi login root --password=
logged in 'root', credentials valid for 10.00 hours

# Create new user "sample"
» devpi user -c sample email=sample@sample.com password=1234
user created: sample

# Login as user "sample"
» devpi login sample --password 1234
logged in 'sample', credentials valid for 10.00 hours
```

But when I try to create the index, it breaks:

```
» devpi index -c sample/prod bases=root/pypi volatile=True
PUT http://devpi.mine/sample/prod
403 Forbidden: no permission to create index sample/prod
```

Why is the newly created user not allowed to create an index?

Comment: Try running `devpi use http://devpi.mine` after login into the `sample` account.

Comment: @Kanguros, I tried that, but it does not make any difference. Actually, in my question you can see that the `PUT` request is being sent to the right `devpi` server, but somehow the server refuses to complete the request.

Comment: @Kanguros I have traced the error back to the flag `--restrict-modify root` (my devpi  server is running in a docker container which uses that flag by default). Removing that flag lets me to creates indexes. I was under the impression that `restrict-modify` only applies to user management, not to index management.